# Set the start date 30 days within today and the end date 30 days after start date using antd rangepicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, antd, daterangepicker

New to antd.

So I have a piece of codes which can select a dynamic range by using onCalendarChange and disabledDate.

Couldn't figure how to set the start date 30 days within today and the end date 30 days after start date.

```
    const [dates, setDates] = useState([]);
    const disabledDate = current => {
        if (!dates || dates.length === 0) {
            return false;
        }
        const tooLate = dates[0] && current.diff(dates[0], 'days') > 30;
        const tooEarly = dates[1] && dates[1].diff(current, 'days') > 30;
        return tooEarly || tooLate;
    };

    <RangePicker
      disabledDate={disabledDate}
      onCalendarChange={value => setDates(value)}
    />
```

Thanks for much for help in advance!

Comment: can you give some examples of how you want the selection to be?

Comment: if today is 10/01, the start date can only be between 10/01-10/30
depend on the selection of the start date, for example 10/20, the end date can only be between 10/21-11/21